# How to check lxml version in OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, lxml

Some way how to check it from Linux OpenSUSE console?

```
 from lxml import etree
```

is not working. Thanks!

Comment: Using python v2.20 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with *python -c*:

```
:~$ python -c "from lxml.etree import LIBXML_VERSION, LXML_VERSION;print(LIBXML_VERSION, LXML_VERSION)"
((2, 9, 3), (3, 6, 1, 0))
```